# Not able to capture output of "who -m" command in JAVA

Tags: java, unix

I want to get the IP address of logged in user of the telnet session

So I have written the following code:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/usr/bin/who", "-m"});
p1.waitFor();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
String line = reader.readLine();

System.out.println("line=" + line);
reader.close();
```

But I am getting the output as "null".

Where as expected output is: 
linus    pts/1        Dec 10 03:48 (172.21.235.48)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the replies.

From the reply of "dystroy" I understood that *-m* was creating problem.

I tried *--m* and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you shouldn't pass the `-m` option.

This works for me :

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/usr/bin/who"});
```

Comment: "who" returns details of all the logged in users.
I need the data of my login.

How can I ensure which one is the detail of my login (who -m does this)

Answer (score 0):

Try to consume the input stream from the process before calling `waitFor()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script which will receive parameter (option) from your java program.
Then you can run your shell script from java like this -

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/PATH/test.sh","-m");
    String line; 
    Process process=pb.start(); 
    java.io.InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    return br;
```

Now in test.sh, you cab grab the argument and run the command -

```
/usr/bin/who $1 (needs to check, not sure)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In this case, there's no difference between running a shell script and the command itself.

Comment: How exactly does this help??

Comment: It's not a workaround, because it doesn't work around the issue (it doesn't change anything).

Comment: how ? in shell script you can call the command, you want. I have just called shell script which will call required command with argument.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It's working for me and returns the same output  as `who -m` UNIX command.

```
import java.io.*;
public class UserPB
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

                try {
                //      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/u01/app/chdir/user.sh");
                        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("who");
                        Process p;
                        p = pb.start();
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                        System.out.println("Your Host Details--->"+input.readLine());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
```